# Meteor using Template.registerHelpers failed to find function

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

I write meteor 1.2.1 registerHelper function like：

```
Template.registerHelper('UserisRole',
function(user, role){
if (user.roles[Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP].indexOf(role)>-1)
  return true;
else {
  return false;
  }
});
...
...
Template.TableActionBtns.events({

'click #btnRemove': function(){
var tmpuser=Meteor.user();
    if (UserisRole(tmpuser,'admin')) {     //error happens for UserisRole is not defined
  Accounts.users.remove({id:this._id});
        //Session.set("albumID", this._id);

    } else {

        var title = "Remove not allowed";

        var msg = "Please login as admin to remove it";

        toastr.warning(msg, title);

    }

}});
```

I register the UserisRole function before， why the meteor template is still can not find the function I register above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You helper loading befor template or something like that.

Search on stack for meteor project directory structure.

- `meteor project` dir

  -`client` - dir

  - has a `lib` subdir

you can place you javascript in meteor project folder, in client folder and in lib folder. The result will be different.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
UserisRole = function (user, role) {
  if (user.roles[Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP].indexOf(role)>-1) {
    return true;
  } else{
    return false;
  }
}

Template.TableActionBtns.events({
  'click #btnRemove': function(){
    var tmpuser=Meteor.user();
    if (UserisRole(tmpuser,'admin')) {     //error happens for UserisRole is not defined
      Accounts.users.remove({id:this._id});
      //Session.set("albumID", this._id);
    } else {
      toastr.warning("Please login as admin to remove it", "Remove not allowed");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I know it work, I just want to know how the registerHelper works, since I need to make this function work on all templates.

Comment: I do not think you know meteor.js the template and helper is use the default of meteor.js.

Answer (score 0):

To access global helpers you need to use it like below

```
UI._globalHelpers['UserisRole'](user, role)
```

but better way of doing is create a function and register that function with the global helper

```
UserisRole = function(user, role){
   if (user.roles[Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP].indexOf(role)>-1)
     return true;
  else {
    return false;
  }
}

Template.registerHelper(UserisRole);
```

In this way you can call the function in js with simple function call

```
UserisRole(user,role)
```

or in Template

```
{{UserisRole user role}}
```